# Overriding parts of function definition

Tags: r

With `assignInNamespace` you can override package functions. That works fine, but I have to override only **one line** out of 200 function lines. So I have to copy & paste much code. :(

Is there a way to override only parts of a function? Only a variable or another function inside the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  You can use `body<-`.  Here's a simple example that changes the last line of `setNames`

```
setNames                          ## original function
# function (object = nm, nm) 
# {
#     names(object) <- nm
#     object
# }
# <bytecode: 0x45367a8>
# <environment: namespace:stats>
as.list(body(setNames))           ## look at the function body as a list
# [[1]]
# `{`
# 
# [[2]]
# names(object) <- nm
#
# [[3]]
# object
#
body(setNames)[[3]] <- quote(nm)  ## replace the last line with 'nm'
setNames
# function (object = nm, nm) 
# {
#     names(object) <- nm
#     nm
# }
#<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Note that you can use `grep` to find where a certain variable is located in the function body

```
grep("object", body(setNames))
# [1] 2 3
```

Comment: thanky you very much. So I only have to find out how to get `body()` from a non-visible function of a package

Comment: You can view the function with `package:::function`

Comment: Can I replace details from an "language object" like `gsub` works for strings? E.g. replace all `(x > 0)` with `(any(x > 0))` in the function body. Then some of my code would be even shorter/nicer.

Comment: It would require a bit more code since `gsub` returns a character vector and the replacement must be an expression.

Comment: `bar <- function(x) if (x < 0) 0 else x; body(bar);
body(bar) <- parse(text=gsub("x < 0",                           "any(x < 0)",deparse(body(bar)))); body(bar)`  seems to work